# How to Identify the Row of a DataGrid using XAML w/ MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm converting an event-driven app to MVVM and trying to minimize the code-behind. One of the views has a DataGrid, and I've placed a column in it with a UserControl that implements ICommandSource. When you click the control (a "LinkLabel"), the app should launch a new tab for the bound object of the DataRow. So I've bound the SelectedItem prop of the DataGrid to a corresponding property in the ViewModel. Everything works fine, as long as the user selects the DataRow first and then clicks the LinkLabel. But this isn't typical user behavior.

My question is: How can I get the DataGrid to select the parent DataRow prior to firing the Command? I imagine that's not conceptually what the solution will be, but it (hopefully) gets the point across.

**DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid Name="dgPeople" MouseDoubleClick="dgPeople_MouseDoubleClick"
      ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfPeople}" SelectedValuePath="DatabaseId" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True"
      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
      Grid.Row="1" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="*">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <view:LinkLabel Content="{Binding FullName}" 
                                 Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=LaunchPersonDetailCmd}"
                                 FontWeight="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
             </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     ...
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Title" Binding="{Binding JobTitle}"
                         Width="*" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}"
                         Width="*" />
     ...
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I can provide other code as needed, but nothing else seems immediately relevant.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this. The view-only way is to use a behaviour that watches for click messages bubbling up the hierarchy and manipulates the visual tree directly, but personally I think it's much better to do it in the view model. I'd need to see your LinkLabel control but if it's anything like the standard WPF controls then it should also have a CommandParameter that you can use to bind to the row data context and pass as a parameter into your command handler.Then it's just a matter of having that handler set the SelectedItem to whatever was passed in.

What I suspect is that your LinkLabel is not actually a necessary control and that it can be replaced with a regular data template containing a templated button that will easily support what you're trying to do, but I'd need more details about what that control actually does.

Comment: Thanks Mark. You're right about the LinkLabel. It's really just a Label that is formatted to look like a hyperlink and then is extended to implement ICommandSource, so it does take a CommandParameter. It probably could have been done more simply as a DataTemplate, but it works well and I won't mess with it.

Comment: I'll tinker around with the parameter approach - that's a good idea. Thanks again. DPH

Comment: Following up. You were exactly right. I got rid of the LinkLabel and replaced it  with a DataTemplate with a styled button. I'm still tweaking the specifics, but this is a much cleaner solution... oh, and using the CommandParameter of the button to pass context. Thanks again. DPH